# Mixing high-current and digital logic on same PCB causes interference

Tags: ground, interference

Lots of questions have been asked about mixing analog and digital on the same board and protect analog from digital noise. I have different situation: my analog current is so high that it cause instability in digital part! I try to control really big BLDC motor using MCU and I try to fit it all on really small PCB, as a result 3.3V and ground get unstable. What would be my considerations in this case?

Photos of the design are here: http://www.dizzy.ai/2017/12/08/interference

Comment: read Henry Ott's book on EMI design or any web topics of similar discussion included in this group.

Comment: Post schematic and layout.

Comment: These type of questions have to be taken on a case by case basis for each design. There can be one or more mechanisms for a single problem (ie you see cross talk between channels, is it inductively or capacitivly coupled? OR common mode noise on both?)

Comment: The link to the picture is broke

Comment: define unstable.

Comment: Oops! That page can’t be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link indicates *Winding resistance is 0.1 Ohm, Power supply is 12V 20A rated*

All DC motors including BLDC have a rated DCR which determines the surge current reached quickly in a time constant of L/DCR when the switch is much lower RdsOn.

This means if full voltage is applied via your H bridge drivers your surge current is 12V/0.1ohm = 120 Amp. This can be supplied by your large E-cap if its ESR is as low as your FET switch and its size C*DCR=T supply is greater than the L/DCR =T load time constant,  meaning **L/C < DCR²**

So I would suggest your power supply is inadequate.

But this does not address your EMI issues.  When there is a loop of this magnitude of current without shielded twisted pairs  any induction into signal wires or conduction ground rise into the logic ground, with more than 1V will result in logic failure.  or perhaps even less)  Star ground from source to isolate Analog (motor + driver

Search [the web for suitable solutions.](https://www.google.ca/search?client=firefox-b-ab&dcr=0&ei=5VMrWpgPx8KPA-OPuqAH&q=0.1%20ohm%20motor%20DCR%20EMI%20design&oq=0.1%20ohm%20motor%20DCR%20EMI%20design&gs_l=psy-ab.3...9086.9577.0.11744.2.2.0.0.0.0.244.399.0j1j1.2.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.nJB9HGO1YIQ)

Comment: Tony, thank you very much for your reply!
First Google result on the subject says "while the basic concepts are relatively simple, implementation is very involved", I guess this is my problem. You suggested shielded power cable, this is fine. Should I also move high-current part of schematic to opposite end of the board instead being on the bottom layer under the logic? Should I add copper layer in between so it serves as a shield? Would you suggest covering digital part with those metal boxes (don't know what's the proper name for those)?

Comment: twisted pairs everywhere carrying large current or high impedance signals. Shielding for extra, but adds 100pF/m, Ferrite CM choke for extra.  and Super low ESR/ESL power/ground planes with caps to match

Comment: Arduino shields are the worst place do drive high current, getting into ADC etc.  tinned brass lids help in some cases. but isolating high dI/dt noise sources from analog and logic is critical. Separation, twisted pair, star low ESL braid  ground/V+ low ESR.... decoupling supply ripple. and best measurement techniques for 1cm probe/gnd length for low noise.